# Can an ExpandableListView has children without parents?

Tags: android

My program imports contacts from some text file and put them into ExpandableListView.
The contacts list file has elements without groups, so some children will be without parents.
I think that I have only one way to use them - to put into special group, for example "No group" or "Others". Is there any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And ExpandableListView without parents would just be a ListView.  So, the answer to your question is no.    You will have to do what you suggest:  create a group to hold all the ungrouped items.